# Getting time difference in just hours momentJS and angular

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm currently using momentJS to find the difference between the current time and the timestamp I have received from a database.

Moment shows the difference as human readable for example it shows 18 hours ago. When it reaches 24 hours it changes to days. Is it possible to change this so that is says 24 hours or 32 hours etc?

This is my function which shows the difference

```
$scope.chris = function dateDiff(created_at_timestamp) 
{
  var start = moment();
  var currentDate = moment(created_at_timestamp);
  return currentDate.from(start);
}
```

Is there a built in function so that I could specify the format of the human readable time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `moment.diff` and `moment.duration` to calculate time duration between dates. To get result in hours use `moment.asHours` method.

```
var startDate = moment([2015, 12, 23, 11, 0, 0]);
var endDate = moment([2015, 12, 24, 12, 30, 0]);

var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var durationAsHours = duration.asHours();

console.log(durationAsHours); // returns 25.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use an angular date or time filter